# git repo access denied after months of no problems

Tags: git-config, github-desktop

Up until today, I've had no problem using GitHub to access my client's source repository. I've been happily working as a developer for 6 months on their project. Over the weekend I shut down my computer. Something I don't do very often. For the first time since the restart, I attempted to push a branch to the remote I get Authentication failed. You may not have permission.... git command line has the same issue. I figure it must have something to do with some environment variable that I had established and lost, or some configuration file that got overwritten somehow, but I don't know how to get it to work again. I'm looking for ~/.ssh/config file because some posts reference it in relation to this. I don't know where to go. git config --get-all doesn't produce any output. Too few parameters it says. Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Did you confirm you still have access to the repo, perhaps via GitHub web portal?

Comment: Yes, I can get to it via the browser. I can also browse it in GitHub. Just can't commit. Or push.

Comment: I checked with a team member and it appears that all of the rest of the developers are using gitlab and that the repository is hosted there. I had always thought it was on GitHub. Anyway, I got a config file into my ~/.ssh directory that allows git command line to push my branch. Now I'm trying to commit and push the branch from within GitHub, but it still fails with Authentication failure. If GitHub only works with GitHub hosted repositories, how did it work for the last 6 months?